# dyld: Library not loaded - how to use ln - s properly?

Tags: osx-mavericks

I literally just got my MacBook back from the repair shop and although (nearly) everything is nice and dandy, I can't launch Gromacs to run some simulations :(

I'm getting the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3f.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/gromacs/bin/grompp
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

From another very similar thread here, I saw the `ln -s` solution so I looked for the `libfftw3f.3.dylib` file and found it in this path `/usr/local/Cellar/fftw/3.3.4/lib/libfftw3f.3.dylib`

Should I try the line `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/fftw/3.3.4/lib/libfftw3f.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfftw3f.3.dylib` or is there a chance I'll break the computer?! Sorry, I'm not much of a programmer and in the past I have messed it up quite badly while learning/working so particularly now that I only just got it back (HDD problem, I didn't break it this time!) I'm even more hesitant.

Would be great if someone could let me know what they think?

Answer (score 0):

You should recompile gromacs to run with whatever has been changed on your system.